# Android Things(ラズパイ３)で WiFiのテザリング設定をするにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

以下のコードで試しましたが、SecurityExceptionとなり設定できませんでした。
マニフェストにはWRITE_SETTINGSを設定しているのですが使用できないのでしょうか？

"Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.androidthings.myproject was not granted  this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS."

```
    private void wifiTetheringOn(){
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    try {
        Method method = wifi.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        Log.i(TAG,method.invoke(wifi, null, true).toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: ", e);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1):

Android6.0からWRITE_SETTINGSのセキュリティレベルが変更になっていたはずです。
ユーザに明示的に許可を得る必要があるはずです。
APIリファレンスのWRITE_SETTINGSのNoteに記載されてます。
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

WRITE_SETTINGSのパーミッション問題について
下記で類似の質問があり、解決しているみたいです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083410/cant-get-write-settings-permission

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。"解決"のとおりやってみたらWRITE_SETTINGSを設定することができ、テザリングも設定することができました。しかしIPアドレスを割り当てることができません。DCHPサーバが起動していないようです